# What is best practice for setting font size based on device?

Tags: ios

I am attempting to scale my app's font size based on the device being used.  What is best practice for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to actually take advantage of the dynamic text features added in iOS 7. That way your user is actually in charge of the font size and your app adjusts as needed. This will give your users who have poor eyesight the best experience.